# How to select and update from one table in one query using object oriented PHP inside class

Tags: php, mysqli

I need to select data i have in my table row after its selection and i update it at that time but is not working .  [Table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4o0IA.png)

```
               class DbHandler {

private $conn;

function __construct() {
    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/DbConnect.php';
    // opening db connection
    $db = new DbConnect();
    $this->conn = $db->connect();
}
  public function updateProfile($profile_picture, $username,$businessname, $town ) {


   $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT profile_information,username,businessname,town from profile_information WHERE profile_id= ?");
   $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE profile_information set profile_picture = ?, username= ?, businessname= ?, town= ? where profile_id= ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ssssi",$profile_picture, $username, $businessname, $town,$profile_id);   
    $stmt->execute();
   $stmt->close();
}

  }
```

**update.php calls above function**

```
                             include './DbHandler.php';
       $db = new DbHandler();
     if (  isset($_POST['profile_picture']) && isset($_POST['username']) &&    isset($_POST['businessname']) && isset($_POST['town'])!= '') {

  $profile_picture = $_POST['profile_picture'];
 $username = $_POST['username'];
 $businessname = $_POST['businessname'];
 $town = $_POST['town'];

 $response = $db->updateProfile( $profile_picture, $username, $businessname,     $town);
                } 
             ?>
```

**This html interface which hosts the form**

```
                        <!doctype html>
                       <html lang="en"
                           <body>
                       <form name="uploadForm" method="post"  action="update_profile.php" >    
                       <label>profilep</label>  <input type="text"  name="profile_picture" > <br><br>
                        <label>Uname</label>  <input type="text" name="username" > <br> <br>
                        <label>BName</label>  <input type="text" name="businessname" >             <br><br>
                       <label>Town </label>   <input type="text" name="town" > <br><br>
                       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /> 
                     </form>  
                      </body>
                     </html>
```

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: `WHERE phone = profile_id= ?` ?????????

Comment: You are preparing the SELECT and UPDATE queries on the same statement handle???? PHP is clever but not that clever

Comment: GIGO! And I guess you are getting Garbage Out

Comment: Not sure why you think you need to SELECT the row before you update the row

Comment: There does not seem to be anything specifically relating to cakePHP in this code

Comment: I was thinking that it will be an easy way to update a specific row of that table because update only query is not working for me.if there is any way to help me update that table only and i remove select query it will be highly appreciated

Answer (score -2):

You can't do two actions in one statement. In your updateProfile method, you need execute a SELECT role, storage the collection in a variable and after do the UPDATE role, like this:

```
public function updateProfile(...)
{
     $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT profile_information,username,businessname,town from profile_information WHERE phone = ? AND profile_id= ?");
     $stmt->bindParam(1, $phone);
     $stmt->bindParam(2, $profile_id);
     $stmt->execute();
     $partial = $stmt->fecthAll();

     for($i = 0, $i < count($partial), $i++)
     {
         $stmtUpdate = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE profile_information set profile_picture = ?, username= ?, businessname= ?, town= ? where profile_id= ?");
         $stmtUpdate->bindParam(1, $profilePicture);
         $stmtUpdate->bindParam(2, $userName);
         $stmtUpdate->bindParam(3, $businessName);
         $stmtUpdate->bindParam(4, $town);
         $stmtUpdate->bindParam(5, $profileId);
         $stmtUpdate->execute();
     }
}
```

Please check your code format, and use the [PSR's](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/) to guide your development.